# Keyword Search Program doesn't work after moving to Python 3 - fault may be with urllib

Tags: python, urllib, keyword

I found this program online that accesses an online txt and searches for a number of keywords, outputting a dictionary with the numbers of each word that is found.

```
import urllib2
import csv
import sys

string_match1 = 'edgar/data/1360901/000136090118000006/0001360901-18- 
000006.txt'

url3 = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/'+string_match1

response3 = urllib2.urlopen(url3)

words = ['anticipate',  'believe', 'depend', 'fluctuate', 'indefinite', 
'likelihood', 'possible', 'predict', 'risk', 'uncertain']

count={}
for elem in words:
    count[elem] = 0

for line in response3:
    elements = line.split()
    for word in words:
        count[word] = count[word]+elements.count(word)

print (count)
```

That worked in Python 2, however when I tried to run it on Python 3 it failed. I thought the problem was with the urllib update. So I changed it myself and also used 2to3.py to get the following:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import csv
import sys

string_match1 = 'edgar/data/1360901/000136090118000006/0001360901-18- 
000006.txt'

url3 = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/'+string_match1

response3 = urllib.request.urlopen(url3)

words = ['anticipate',  'believe', 'depend', 'fluctuate', 'indefinite', 
'likelihood', 'possible', 'predict', 'risk', 'uncertain']

count={}
for elem in words:
    count[elem] = 0

for line in response3:
    elements = line.split()
    for word in words:
        count[word] = count[word]+elements.count(word)

print (count)
```

This got rid of the error, but the program no longer works.  This is the output now: the words in the dictionary are displayed but each count is 0, when it should be non-zero.

[image]

Comment: shouldn't you .read() your request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement below changes on your code:

```
request = urllib.request.Request(url3)

response3 = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

htmlBytes = response3.read()
htmlStr = htmlBytes.decode("utf8")

words = ['anticipate',  'believe', 'depend', 'fluctuate', 'indefinite', 
'likelihood', 'possible', 'predict', 'risk', 'uncertain']

count={}
for elem in words:
    count[elem] = 0

htmlSplit = htmlStr.split('\n')
for elements in htmlSplit:
    for word in words:
        count[word] = count[word]+elements.count(word)
```